# Laravel websockets not showing realtime stats on localhost

Tags: php, laravel, pusher, phpwebsocket, laravel-websockets

I'm trying to set up Laravel web sockets on my localhost but I'm having trouble getting the Real time statistics on the dashboard working.

In my config/broadcasting.php I have updated the pusher array according to the Laravel websockets documentation.

```
'pusher' => [
            'driver' => 'pusher',
            'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
            'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
            'app_id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
            'options' => [
                'cluster' => env('PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
                'encrypted' => true,
                'host' => '127.0.0.1',
                'port' => 6001,
                'scheme' => '
            ],
        ],
```

On the .env I've updated the broadcast driver

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=pusher
PUSHER_APP_ID=local
PUSHER_APP_KEY=local
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=local
```

I have also accordingly updated the bootstrap.js file as follows

```
import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: 'local',
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    encrypted: false,
    disableStats: true,
    wsHost: window.location.hostname,
    wsPort: 6001,
});
```

The pusher version I'm pulling in the composer is

```
 "pusher/pusher-php-server": "^4.1"
```

Having done all that, I do not understand why the real time statistics are not working. The errors I'm getting from the console are

```
POST http://127.0.0.1/laravel-websockets/auth 404 (Not Found)
GET http://127.0.0.1/laravel-websockets/api/local/statistics 404 (Not Found)
```

I'm on Windows and using xampp.

Comment: Only thing that jumps out is `'encrypted' => true,` which I assume should be false on localhost. It's a 404, should be easy to track down.

Answer (score 1):

On the **config/websockts.php** change `enable_statistics=true`

```
'apps' => [
    [
        'id' => env('PUSHER_APP_ID'),
        'name' => env('APP_NAME'),
        'key' => env('PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        'secret' => env('PUSHER_APP_SECRET'),
        'path' => env('PUSHER_APP_PATH'),
        'capacity' => null,
        'enable_client_messages' => false,
        'enable_statistics' => true,
    ],
],
```